# What Kind of Code Can I Not Put Into the onCreate Method

Tags: java, android, oncreate

So I'm making a simple game application that calculates the score in the Main Activity, and then sends this integer to a new Activity. I then have a text View in this new Activity that is suppose to take the integer sent through the intent, and set it as the text of the text View(So basically it sends the score of the User, and displays the score in another Activity). I put this code into the onCreate() of the new Activity, yet it crashes at the line, "ScoreText.setText(score2);" where ScoreText is the text View and score2 is a string. I don't know if I'm not allowed to change the properties of a view in the onCreate(), but it seems as though I can't. I have also tried putting this code into a method, and have the method initiated in the onCreate(), but this crashes the app as well, so I assume I can't put methods into the onCreate() either. So exactly what can I put into the onCreate()? And, how will I change the text of the text View after starting the next activity?

Here's the onCreate() of the New Activity:

```
    TextView ScoreText;
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_level);


    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    Intent info=getIntent();
    int Score=info.getIntExtra("UsersScore", 0);
    String score2=""+Score;
    TextView ScoreText=(TextView)(findViewById(R.id.tvScore));
    ScoreText.setText(score2);

}
```

Log Cat:

```
06-29 23:12:40.459: D/ActivityThread(20281): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
06-29 23:12:40.469: D/ActivityThread(20281): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
06-29 23:12:40.469: D/ActivityThread(20281): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
06-29 23:12:40.939: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(20281): <ConfigWindowMatch:2136>: Format RGBA_8888.
06-29 23:12:41.009: **E**/(20281): <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading
06-29 23:12:41.009: **E**/(20281): <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading
06-29 23:12:43.462: W/dalvikvm(20281): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41642438)
06-29 23:12:43.462: **E**/AndroidRuntime(20281): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-29 23:12:43.462: **E**/AndroidRuntime(20281): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.thewordgame/com.example.thewordgame.LevelActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-29 23:12:43.462: **E**/AndroidRuntime(20281):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
06-29 23:12:43.462: **E**/AndroidRuntime(20281):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
06-29 23:12:43.462: **E**/AndroidRuntime(20281):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
06-29 23:12:43.462: **E**/AndroidRuntime(20281):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
06-29 23:12:43.462: **E**/AndroidRuntime(20281):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-29 23:12:43.462: **E**/AndroidRuntime(20281):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-29 23:12:43.462: **E**/AndroidRuntime(20281):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4953)
06-29 23:12:43.462: **E**/AndroidRuntime(20281):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-29 23:12:43.462: **E**/AndroidRuntime(20281):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-29 23:12:43.462: **E**/AndroidRuntime(20281):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
06-29 23:12:43.462: **E**/AndroidRuntime(20281):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
06-29 23:12:43.462: **E**/AndroidRuntime(20281):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-29 23:12:43.462: **E**/AndroidRuntime(20281): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-29 23:12:43.462: **E**/AndroidRuntime(20281):    at com.example.thewordgame.LevelActivity.onCreate(LevelActivity.java:34)
06-29 23:12:43.462: **E**/AndroidRuntime(20281):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5160)
06-29 23:12:43.462: **E**/AndroidRuntime(20281):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
06-29 23:12:43.462: **E**/AndroidRuntime(20281):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
06-29 23:12:43.462: **E**/AndroidRuntime(20281):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely put that kind of code in the onCreate method.

But looks like ScoreText is not initialized. Check the logs, and put them here if possible. That would give more details about the problem.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-29 23:12:43.462: **E**/AndroidRuntime(20281):    at com.example.thewordgame.LevelActivity.onCreate(LevelActivity.java:34)
```

**What's the code on LevelActivity.onCreate(LevelActivity.java:34) (Line 34)?**

Comment: I have added the logcat

Comment: String score2=""+Score;

Comment: So I commented out that line, then I put "ScoreText.setText("1000");"

Comment: Still crashes the app

Comment: Im sorry, now it's pointing to line 36 which would be the setText line.

Comment: That means your ScoreText is null. Check the layout if the id there matches what you have here.

Comment: <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvScore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LostText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="@dimen/abc_dropdownitem_icon_width" />

Comment: So I transferred the code of the new Activity into a button's onClick() method instead of the onCreate(), and it works perfectly now, I just don't want to make the user press a button to show their score. So there has to be something wrong with putting my setText() code into the onCreate().

Answer (score 0):

You should check that the textview with id `tvScore` exists in your `R.layout.activity_level`. If you have multiple layouts, make sure all of them contain this text view as well.

Comment: Yup everything is in check there

Comment: Can you check that your Intent `info` is not null too?

Comment: Intent intent=new Intent(this, LevelActivity.class);
   intent.putExtra("UsersScore", Score);
   startActivity(intent); //This is what is in the other Activity

Comment: Because your logcat clearly says nullpointer at line 34. If that is the `setText`line, then the `ScoreText` must be null. You have to show us that it is not null and the textview is clearly defined in your layout.

Comment: The edited code now shows where I defined my Text view. And line 34 is  "String score2=""+Score;". Not the setText line.

Comment: Just to be sure, the code that you post is the `LevelActivity`, right?

Comment: Yes, it is the LeveActivty.

Comment: Im sorry, now it's pointing to line 36 which would be the setText line.

Comment: That means your textview *must* be null and undefined. You need to check your `activity_level` again. Make sure they have correct spelling, and do you have layouts defined for different screen size?

Comment: No, I do not have different layouts defined for different screen size

Comment: <TextView android:id="@+id/tvScore" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/LostText" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_marginTop="26dp" android:text="0" android:textSize="@dimen/abc_dropdownitem_icon_width" />

Comment: So I transferred the code of the new Activity into a button's onClick() method instead of the onCreate(), and it works perfectly now, I just don't want to make the user press a button to show their score. So there has to be something wrong with putting my setText() code into the onCreate().